# Creating Multiple QueueConfigurations in CloudFormation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I'm currently trying to write multiple QueueConfigurations into my CloudFormation template. Each is an SQS queue that is triggered when an object is created to a specified prefix. Here's what I have so far:

```
{
    "Resources": {
      "S3Bucket": {
        "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties" : 
          "BucketName" : { "Ref" : "paramBucketName" },
          "LoggingConfiguration" : {
            "DestinationBucketName" : "test-bucket",
            "LogFilePrefix" : { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ { "Ref": "paramBucketName" }, "/" ] ] }
          },
          "NotificationConfiguration" : {
              "QueueConfigurations" : [{
                "Id" : "1",
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "folder1/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-cdc_feeder_prod_hvr_dev"
              }],   
              "QueueConfigurations" : [{
                "Id" : "2",
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "folder2/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-latency_hvr_dev"
              }]
            }                               
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've encountered the error saying `Encountered unsupported property Id`. I thought that by defining the ID, I would be able to avoid the `Duplicate object key` error.

Does anyone know how to create multiple triggers in a single CloudFormation template? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be structured like the below, There should only be one `QueueConfigurations` attribute
that contains all queue configurations within it. Also the `Id` parameter is not a valid property.

```
{
    "Resources": {
      "S3Bucket": {
        "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties" : 
          "BucketName" : { "Ref" : "paramBucketName" },
          "LoggingConfiguration" : {
            "DestinationBucketName" : "test-bucket",
            "LogFilePrefix" : { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ { "Ref": "paramBucketName" }, "/" ] ] }
          },
          "NotificationConfiguration" : {
              "QueueConfigurations" : [{
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "folder1/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-cdc_feeder_prod_hvr_dev"
              },
              {
                "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                "Filter" : { 
                  "S3Key" : {
                    "Rules" : {
                      "Name" : "prefix",
                      "Value" : "folder2/"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Queue" : "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-latency_hvr_dev"
              }]
            }                               
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

There is more information about [QueueConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html) in the documentation.

Comment: No problem @ClaireLe glad I could help